# Loading data from a store inside an other store

Tags: reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

I'm trying to give my `flux/react` application a better shape.

I would like to write functional code with pure components and I really like the `redux` concepts. But, I have to stick with flux for this one.

I was wondering if there was something wrong in loading data in a store from an other store.

Imagine that I have a db with some categories and some geographical array given from the back-end. I need this stuff in many different sections of the app. So I have an action that I initialize in `ComponentDidMount` where I need it:

- `AppAction.init()` that makes a ajax call and get `_categories and _geographics`

Now I have my AppStore listening and storing the data.

ComponentA uses the getters from AppStore ans StoreA to manipulate the data and pass it down to my components.

I would like to move all the data logic in StoreA putting inside a getter that takes the data from AppStore.

In StoreA
          `let data = AppStore.getData();`

Do you guys see any drawback in doing this?

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/dispatcher.html Example of a similar thing done in the facebook docs. You will want to probably use a waitFor to ensure AppStore has set its data before StoreA uses it

Comment: Thank you Mike!
It seams a nightmare to use the waitFor method, I'm clearly considering of duplicating the logic in multiple stores, and maybe to listen to the same action in more stores...
Can you explain me better why I should consider this method? It seams that connecting stores together is not a great Idea if the applications grows.

Comment: maybe not duplicating the logic... but yes listening to the same action in multiple stores.

Comment: Yes if you have 30 stores and they all rely on each other I can see it being a nightmare. waitFor guarantees that one stores updates before another when listening on the same action be dispatched. If it is 2 or 3 stores I don't see it being too big of a problem but then again I don't have the knowledge of how big your project is or can get to be

Comment: Your answer is really to the point so I upvoted it.
This project is big, so I will eventually consider not doing it... But I'm still thinking on it...